# MapReduce Task fails Python

Tags: python, hadoop, mapreduce

I seem to be getting the following error:

```
14/07/02 23:29:14 INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id : attempt_1395688818137_1239_r_000001_2, Status : FAILED
Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: PipeMapRed.waitOutputThreads(): subprocess failed with code 1
        at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed.waitOutputThreads(PipeMapRed.java:330)
        at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed.mapRedFinished(PipeMapRed.java:543)
        at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeReducer.close(PipeReducer.java:134)
        at org.apache.hadoop.io.IOUtils.cleanup(IOUtils.java:237)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.runOldReducer(ReduceTask.java:487)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.run(ReduceTask.java:411)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:162)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1491)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:157)
```

I have included `#!/usr/bin/python` as per other forums. But i still seem to get the same result. Can someone help me in figuring out what the other problems might be?

Comment: just error log not enough to predict the reason for error. add more info like what you are trying to achieve. if possible snap of M R python code lines

Comment: All this is saying is that a subprocess died. We need someone familiar with the hadoop system to explain where to look for the *subprocess's* crash messages.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried including #!/usr/bin/env python instead of #!/usr/bin/python  ?  this will allow the operating system to run them as stand-alone executables

Comment: Both of those allow the system to run them as stand-alone executables. The difference is that `#!/usr/bin/env python` searches for Python on the user's `$PATH` while `#!/usr/bin/python` specifies the exact location of the Python to use.